# Query against a table of multi-day intervals, grouping counts by day?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

Imagine a mysql table that looks like this:

```
Interval
--------------------------
id          INT, NOT NULL
start       DATETIME, NOT NULL
finish      DATETIME, NOT NULL
```

I'd like an efficient query that produces the number of intervals that span noon on a range of days.  So that if I had data that looks like this:

```
id      start                 finish
-------------------------------------------------
1       2013-01-12 08:00:00   2013-01-17 02:00:00 
2       2013-01-12 15:00:00   2013-01-13 18:00:00 
3       2013-01-13 08:00:00   2013-01-13 09:00:00 
4       2013-01-14 11:00:00   2013-01-15 08:00:00 
5       2013-01-14 02:00:00   2013-01-17 01:00:00 
6       2013-01-15 20:00:00   2013-01-16 08:00:00
```

I could run it and receive a result set like this:

```
Timestamp             Count
-----------------------------
2013-01-12 12:00:00   1
2013-01-13 12:00:00   2
2013-01-14 12:00:00   3
2013-01-15 12:00:00   2
2013-01-16 12:00:00   2
```

I can do this brutishly by querying for the minimum start and maximum finish, then doing this:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM Interval 
WHERE start <= @noon_timestamp AND finish >= @noon_timestamp
```

for each day in the range, but that seems ugly and horrible.

Is there a way to do it better?  And if so, can you do it with SqlAlchemy's syntax?  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Interval
WHERE @noon_timestamp BETWEEN start AND finish
```

Comment: You are missing the GROUP BY day.  Maybe `GROUP BY DAYOFYEAR(start)`

Comment: @Linger If I understand correctly, he's going to iterate `@noon_timestamp` over the days, and he wants the total for each of those values.

Comment: That's the result I'm looking for, but I'm trying to avoid running the query multiple times.  I'd really like to find a way to use GROUP BY, but you can't just group by the day, since many intervals span more than one day.

Comment: If you have another table containing all the noon timestamps, you can join with that and group by that column. I don't think MySQL has any way to synthesize a table like this automatically.